# Sort a string so I can use it with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a text string that look like this, it could be a lot bigger. Same UserID can come up several times.

> [{"UserID":"400","username":"john doe","GroupID":"11","GroupName":"Missing", "Money":"2300"},
>    {"UserID":"500","username":"jon doe","GroupID":"12","GroupName":"Missing", "Money":"2400"},
>    {"UserID":"600","username":"jen doe","GroupID":"13","GroupName":"Missing", "Money":"1100"},
>    {"UserID":"400","username":"john doe","GroupID":"11","GroupName":"Missing", "Money":"1400"}]

I want to sort this some how so can ask LINQ questions about it.

Like the total sum of all the UserID´s money, total sum of a UserID´s money and the username.

Should I put it in a class or what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Looks like JSON. You should use a JSON parser.

Comment: Deserialize it into object structure and use LINQ to calculate the results.

Comment: If that's JSON, you should use a library (recommendations for which are offtopic for StackOverflow really) such as Newtonsoft, which has handy [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) capabilities.

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: You could just use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to be dealing with these objects often then I would definitely make classes to represent them to make it easier to deserialize the JSON strings.  If not then you can just roll something quick and dirty.  Either way I think you are going to want to use the Json.NET library; it will make your life easier.  Install it in your project by running this command in the package manager console:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

For the quick and dirty solution, given a string called `json`, you can do this:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq           // Namespace
.JArray                        // Class
.Parse(json)                   // Static method to parse string into a JArray
.Select(x => new               // Select anonymous types
{
    UserId = x["UserID"],
    Username = x["username"],
    GroupId = x["GroupID"],
    GroupName = x["GroupName"],
    Money = x["Money"],
})
.GroupBy(x => x.UserId)        // Group by user id.
.ContinueWithRemainingQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

> Should I put it in a class or what's the best way to do this?

1. That would be the first step you might want to do.
2. The next step might be to [transform the JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to your class
3. [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx) your results
4. Fire your application logic like summation etc.